# Calling a Rest Service from a servlet

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to create a servlet that provide access to a REST service. Is it wise to use jersey client API for this task or is there a easier way to do this.

Comment: So you want some kind of proxy?

Comment: yes I need a proxy....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a good reason to make the servlet call the REST service, instead of the client calling directly  the REST service? I mean, does the servlet adds some logic, security, or something?

In this case, yes, it would be a good idea to use Jersey client API.

Since Jersey is the RI for JSR-339 (JAX-RS 2.0), you may also directly use JSR-339 APIs: [Overview of the Client API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jaxrs-client001.htm#BABBIHEJ). This way, your code will also run on a Java EE 7 compliant server (Wildfly 8.x, Glassfish 4.x) without packaging the jersey client in your servlet deliverable.